# psutil network monitoring script

Tags: python, psutil

I'm trying to create a script to monitor basic server resources:- CPU, RAM, DISK and NETWORK IN AND OUT(in mega bytes /sec).
Unfortunately while the cpu, memory and disk parts work, the network function always shows 0.0 bytes in or out, even while there is actual traffic(yum update -y).
Please do help and bear in mind that I'm a complete noob at Python, this is just a practice project. Thanks in advance.

Any suggestions to make it more optimised are welcomed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#Module psutil needs to be installed via pip3 first.
#Python script to Monitor Server Resources.

import time
import psutil

cpu_thresh = 50.0
cpu_pct = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)

if cpu_pct >= cpu_thresh:
    print("CPU Warning, CPU at ",cpu_pct, "percent")

mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
mem_thresh = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 #500MB

if mem_thresh >= mem.available:
    print("Memory Usage Warning only", mem.available /1024 /1024, "MB available")

partition1 = '/'
disk1 = psutil.disk_usage(partition1)
disk_thresh = 85.0

if disk_thresh <= disk1[3]:
    print("Root volume usage warning", disk1[3], "% used")

def net_in(inf = "eth0"):   #change the inf variable according to the interface
  net_in_ps = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True, nowrap=True)[inf]
  net_in_1 = net_in_ps.bytes_recv
  time.sleep(1)
  net_in_2 = net_in_ps.bytes_recv
  net_in_result = net_in_2 - net_in_1
  net_in_result_mbps = net_in_result /1024 /1024
  print(net_in_result_mbps)
  net_in_thresh = 1.5
  if net_in_result_mbps <= net_in_thresh:
      print("Network in Warning, NetSpeed at:", net_in_result_mbps, "mbps")

def net_out(inf = "eth0"):   #change the inf variable according to the interface
  net_out_ps = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True, nowrap=True)[inf]
  net_out_1 = net_out_ps.bytes_sent
  time.sleep(1)
  net_out_2 = net_out_ps.bytes_sent
  net_out_result = net_out_2 - net_out_1
  net_out_result_mbps = net_out_result /1024 /1024
  print(net_out_result_mbps)
  net_out_thresh = 1.5
  if net_out_result_mbps <= net_out_thresh:
      print("Network out Warning, NetSpeed at:", net_out_result_mbps, "mbps")
net_in()
net_out()
```

Comment: what's the output when you `print(psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True, nowrap=True))` ?

Comment: You only poll the ethernet-port once in your functions. So your calculations will always = 0 because `1000 - 1000 == 0`. Also, it's semantics but you're writing "mbps" while it should be "MB/s" because you're calculating with bytes, not bits.

Comment: You should also consider doing both the input / output in the same function, so that you don't have to do the exact same polling twice in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your functions only return `0` is because when you calculate the difference after your `time.sleep(1)` command, you don't poll the interface for the new statistics. You're basically calculating `1000-1000`.

I've corrected your code, and changed the output to Megabytes Instead of Megabits, because `psutil` returns bytes, not  bits:

```
def net_usage(inf = "eth0"):   #change the inf variable according to the interface
    net_stat = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True, nowrap=True)[inf]
    net_in_1 = net_stat.bytes_recv
    net_out_1 = net_stat.bytes_sent
    time.sleep(1)
    net_stat = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True, nowrap=True)[inf]
    net_in_2 = net_stat.bytes_recv
    net_out_2 = net_stat.bytes_sent

    net_in = round((net_in_2 - net_in_1) / 1024 / 1024, 3)
    net_out = round((net_out_2 - net_out_1) / 1024 / 1024, 3)

    print(f"Current net-usage:\nIN: {net_in} MB/s, OUT: {net_out} MB/s")
```

Output:

```
Current net-usage:
IN: 24.263 MB/s, OUT: 0.421 MB/s
```

Comment: Thanks @Hampus Larsson! I just figured it out too. Really basic mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by adding a very simple step:-

```
  net_out_ps1 = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True, nowrap=True)[inf]
  net_out_1 = net_out_ps1.bytes_sent
  time.sleep(1)
  net_out_ps2 = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True, nowrap=True)[inf]
  net_out_2 = net_out_ps2.bytes_sent
```

I had to collect the data once before the sleep and then again after the sleep.
Very simple basic mistake.
However if someone can help optimise the code further I'd appreciate it.
Thanks again.